# Data collection with ADK

Tags: android, android-sensors, adk

I need to sample 6 accelerometers at 30hz.

I want to log the data at my android phone. So i was thinking of using the ADK and the arduino Mega ADK board for this.

My question is whether the bandwidth from arduino board to android will be large enough?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the bandwidth to the arduino will be large enough

Comment: is down and up the same? So it would reach normal USB transmission speeds?

Comment: It would not reach anything - let's do the math: you want to send 30 Values in the second for 6 channels - let's say you sample with 32bit - thats 4 bytes - so 30*6*4 bytes/s = 720 bytes/s - thats like nothing for USB - you could even pump that over bluetooth SPP and don't have to deal with USB/ADK at all  ;-)